# Fetch is not defined at Object.clientLogger.<computed> [as error] (/node_modules/next-auth/utils)

Tags: authentication, testing, next.js, jestjs, next-auth

Since I've installed next-auth (4.24.5) into my project, my tests are breaking, telling that fetch is not defined.

```
ReferenceError: fetch is not defined
    at Object.clientLogger.<computed> [as error] (/node_modules/next-auth/utils/logger.js:99:9)
    at _callee$ (/node_modules/next-auth/react/index.js:528:22)
    at tryCatch (/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:45:16)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:133:17)
    at Generator.throw (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/regeneratorRuntime.js:74:21)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/supertgo/programas/em-cash/wallet.em.cash/simulador-front.em.cash/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:3:24)
    at _throw (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:25:9
```

"jest": "^29.5.0",
"msw": "^2.0.13",

I am using the newest node version and i don't think this is a jest problem because i've switched to vitest and found the same errror.

Can someone help me?